# How to auto post in the facebook using the facebook username in php

Tags: php, facebook

I am new to the Facebook auto post.

I used the codes like using the facebook id, But now i have do same thing using the facebook username.

May i get any suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @arkascha win's the most nonconstructive comment of the year award! If you don't want to see Facebook related posts you should place the tag in your ignore list. Comments like that one you made do not help anyone and are only contributing to the surrounding noise. Please refrain from such comments.

Comment: All I can say is: lol. I do not see why one cannot say what is simply true. But all fine, let's not fight here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please download the facebook sdk file below is the link
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

```
<?php
  // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
  // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
  require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                      'link' => 'www.example.com',
                                      'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                                 ));
        echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

        // Give the user a logout link 
        echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                       'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                       )); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, so print a link for the user to login
      // To post to a user's wall, we need publish_stream permission
      // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
      // need to specify it here.
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    } 

  ?>      

  </body> 
</html>
```

Above code is the Post a link using the Graph API

Comment: All you did here was copy paste the example from the documentation with no additional explanations... Furthermore, you posted a dead link.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook usernames are unique. They are used in the URL of your profile so you can rest assured that there will be no duplicate usernames.

As such, the Facebook user_id and username parameters are mostly interchangeable. Wherever you can use one, you can use the other.

For example, to get Mark Zuckerberg's profile information, I can query this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/4
```

That will give me this:

```
{
  id: "4",
  name: "Mark Zuckerberg",
  first_name: "Mark",
  last_name: "Zuckerberg",
  link: "http://www.facebook.com/zuck",
  username: "zuck",
  gender: "male",
  locale: "en_US"
}
```

Yes, Mark's user id is 4!

Now, lets try the same thing only instead of his user id, we'll supply his username:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/zuck
```

You can see that this returns the same results.

Comment: How to post some text like 'I have posted the deals' using this? friend

Comment: Hi Lix thanks for the support.. Actually https://graph.facebook.com/feed this one... instead of the facebookid i need to use username.... thats my problem

Comment: Have you tried simply replacing the userid with the username? For example: `$facebook->api('/zuck/feed'...`

Comment: yes..,. but without the facebook connection, how can u get the accesstoken to share the posts and need to share posts by username instead of the facebookid

Comment: Well, if you have the username you can easily retrieve the user_id, so you can use the user_id for anything after that.

Comment: no not yet... actually i need to share by username only... no need of userid friend

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. If you have the username, and an access token, you can use both of them to make a post. I still don't really understand the problem.

Comment: $Post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/feed";
   $post_arg = array("access_token" => FACEBOOK_SECRETKEY, "message" => 'hi every one',"id" => 'username',"method" => "post" ); this one i am going to user.. here  how can i get the facebook access token and so and so

Comment: Why are you forced to use the username?

Comment: thats my requirement... user should enter the facebook username and twitter username in his profile. so while posting the deal the update should post in his wall...

Comment: You could just hide the id from the user but still use it behind the scenes.... no?

Comment: ya.... But user will not connect throw the facebook... he just entering the username only..

Comment: Hi friend i found how to get access token... can u tell me this can be applicable for the username instead of the facebookid